# Structured data Product vs. Course

Tags: seo, structured-data

I'm implementing structured data for a company that provides courses. It's a for profit company and the courses are implemented as schema Product.

However, in google search console I'm getting a warning "No global identifier provided (e.g., gtin, mpn, isbn)" which doesn't exist for Course.

Should I be using Course instead of Product?

If yes, how would I go around to making sure the price still appears in the google search?

Answer (score 1):

Check the following **[Google requirement for structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies#relevance)**:

> Relevance
>
> Your structured data should be a true representation of the
> page content.

Therefore, it may be useful to use a top-level type such as Course for web pages representing a course.

In order to add a commercial element to your course markup, you can use the property **[offers](https://schema.org/offers)** of the **[type Course](https://schema.org/Course)** and embed markup for the type **[Offer](https://schema.org/Offer)** with commercial data for each of your courses.

It may also be useful to check the **[Google guide for the type Course](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/course)**.